# Nextjs themes with colors

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, themes, css-variables

How to make theming with color picking for elements?
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUQTQ.png)

I tried css vars and change document classname, but I'm not sure this is the right way.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* :root, 
:root.green{
  --bg-color: green;
}
:root.red{
  --bg-color: red;
}
:root.dark {
    --bg-color: #121212;
    --text-color: #45adfe;
} */

.slate[data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color: #E2E8F0;
}
.slate[data-theme="dark"] {
    --bg-color: #EBF0F7;
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear, please add more reference to it, what exactly you want to implement

Comment: @adityanithariya 
I think the example will convey the idea better
[link](https://streamable.com/rud324)
or
[link](https://ui.shadcn.com/themes)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MaybeRainQ Check this [repo](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui) of one your examples for switching themes

Answer (score 1):

You could use [tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors) for this, it creates two separate themes for dark and light modes and you could just define opposite colors with the same names to make it work.

A simple example, in tailwind.config.js you define:

```
plugins: [
  createThemes({
    light: {
      white: '#ffffff'
      ...
    }
    dark: {
      white: '#000000'
      ...
    }
```

And everytime you use `-white` as color (like `text-white` for instance), it will switch to the opposite on the opposite mode.
With this method you could also use `dark:` and `light:` tailwind prefixes to define different colors.

The package also persists the user choice in localStorage, so the theme doesn't switch back at every page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am trying to build the same thing, but I can change the color scheme for the current page only, I did this by adding those classes that you can copy from shadcn, in such a way

```
// global.css
.light-blue {}
.dark-blue {}
.light-rose {}
.dark-rose {}
```

And creating a component ThemeChanger.tsx

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { SunIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import { MoonIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

function ThemeChanger() {
  const { setTheme, theme } = useTheme();
  const [color, setColor] = useState("default");

  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("");
  const [selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme] = useState("");

  const colors = [
    { name: "zinc", hex: "#52525b" },
    { name: "slate", hex: "#475569" },
    { name: "stone", hex: "#57534e" },
    { name: "gray", hex: "#4b5563" },
    { name: "neutral", hex: "#525252" },
    { name: "red", hex: "#dc2626" },
    { name: "rose", hex: "#e11d48" },
    { name: "orange", hex: "#ea580c" },
    { name: "green", hex: "#22c55e" },
    { name: "blue", hex: "#3b82f6" },
    { name: "yellow", hex: "#facc15" },
    { name: "violet", hex: "#9f7aea" },
  ];

  const handleColorClick = (selectedColor: string) => {
    setColor(selectedColor);
    setSelectedColor(selectedColor);
  };

  const handleThemeClick = (selectedTheme: string) => {
    setTheme(selectedTheme);
    setSelectedTheme(selectedTheme);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = `${theme}-${color}`;
  }, [theme, color]);

  return (
    <div className="border rounded-sm w-mobile p-4 py-8">
      <h1 className="ml-2 mb-4 text-2xl font-bold">Customize</h1>
      <h2 className="ml-2 mb-2 text-base">
        Choose a Color or Theme for your Portfolio Website.
      </h2>
      <h2 className="ml-2 mb-2 text-base">Choose a Color Scheme:</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-1 p-2 border rounded-sm">
        {colors.map((colorItem, index) => (
          <Button
            variant={"outline"}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleColorClick(colorItem.name)}
            className={`flex rounded justify-start items-center gap-2 ${
              selectedColor === colorItem.name
                ? theme === "dark"
                  ? "border-2 border-white"
                  : "border-2 border-black"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            <span
              className={`min-w-4 min-h-4 rounded-full`}
              style={{ backgroundColor: colorItem.hex }}
            ></span>
            {colorItem.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + colorItem.name.slice(1)}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <h2 className="mt-2 ml-2 mb-2 text-base">Choose a default Theme :</h2>
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <Button
          className={`rounded flex gap-4 items-center ${
            selectedTheme === "light" && `border-2 border-black`
          }`}
          variant={"outline"}
          onClick={() => handleThemeClick("light")}
        >
          <SunIcon /> Light Mode
        </Button>
        <Button
          className={`rounded flex gap-4 items-center ${
            selectedTheme === "dark" && `border-2 border-white`
          }`}
          variant={"outline"}
          onClick={() => handleThemeClick("dark")}
        >
          <MoonIcon />
          Dark Mode
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ThemeChanger;
```